# What's the cleanest way to create dynamic layout according to selected item in a spinner?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, layout

Im trying to figure out, what is the cleanest solution to arrange a layout according to the item selected in my spinner.

In my spinner i have values representing pace for running MAS (max aerobic speed) - 800m - 1500m - 5000m - 10 000m - Half marathon & Marathon and for each of those the layout displayed gonna change.

For example if it's MAS selected there will be time indicator for 100m-200m-400m-1000m and various percentage for those distance like 85% - 90% - 100% - 105% so close 16 label + value textview

If the item selected is marathon, there will be time indicator for 1000m - 2000m - 5k - 10k- 15k - half - 30k - 40k - 42k195 so only 0 textview

Would it be better to create a single layout and set visible/invisible textview according to my needs ?

Or having "hardcoded" layout that i returned according to the item selected ?

Hope i'm clear enough, i know that lot of things are possible but i'm really trying to be as clean as possible and i'm not satisfied with either solutions i've written above

Comment: A RecyclerView is probably what you want. It's the typical way to show dynamic content like that. If you're not familiar with it you might want to start reading this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview . It might be hard to grasp how it works at first if you don't know it, but it's probably the way to go

Comment: @IvoBeckers isnt a recyclerview an optimized way to "recycle" components when scrolling ? i always thought it was that and that's not really my problem here. Imagine here that for the 7 differents values in my spinner, i'm gonna display a different layout everytime. There's no scroll at all

Comment: well, it does do that recycling in case there is scrolling. But it also works fine for showing rows that fit the screen. I wouldn't know a better solution for dynamic content like that but maybe someone else knows a better solution

Comment: How about using a fragment placeholder that you do transactions of different layouts on?

Comment: @Zain it's part of the reflection, with your answer every different fragment would be "hardcoded" xml right ? And i'm asking myself if that's clean or if it's better to create programmatically layout using variables

Comment: Try out jetpack compose for this spinner, https://medium.com/@manojbhadane/outlined-spinner-in-jetpack-compose-9c392d9975a2

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your UI but general approach is views differ a lot we put them in separate fragments/XMLs. Having separate views in XML is easier to read and develop. Performance wise it is faster to create views programmatically than inflating XMLs, but you are compromising readability.

- So if your screens differ a lot, you would need to show hide a lot of views, hence have a lot of code handling that in one place, I would go with different XMLs for each screen.
- If you need to show/hide 3-4 views, I would do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you'll provide your UI. But in any cases you can choose one of next variants:

- XML layout;
- Creation views programmaticaly;
- ViewStub - an invisible, zero-sized View that can be used to lazily inflate layout resources at runtime(good article about ViewStub [here](https://proandroiddev.com/viewstub-on-demand-inflate-view-or-inflate-lazily-layout-resource-e56b8c39398b));
- Jetpack Compose - Android’s modern toolkit for building native UI(more [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose)).

So, I can suggest you to use ViewStub or Jetpack Compose as more clean and modern approaches.